# Swift 5 & iOS 13 UISearchController wrong presenting and dismissing behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, ios13, swift5

While i was updating my project to iOS 13 i faced with unusual issue.
I have logic for showing and handling some `UISearchController` actions (code below), all parts were working perfectly in iOS 11 & 12.

My task was to add search button at navigation bar to show `UISearchController` after button action.

But in iOS 13, i got 2 issues:

Code that invokes from button action

```
func showSearch() {
        let searchResultsController = LUSearchResultsViewController()...
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            searchController.isActive = true
        }
}
```

Only one solution helps me to show search controller without any diffs from previous iOS versions.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            searchController.isActive = true
}
```

Code that works on iOS 13, on iOS 11 and 12 code works without **asyncAfter**

Code that helps me to hide `UISearchController` and set navigation bar initial state **in iOS 11 and 12, and not in 13**. After tapping **cancel** on SearchBar, `UISearchController` begins to call delegate methods.

```
  //MARK: UISearchControllerDelegate


    public func willDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
         self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
```

**BUT**

After setting `navigationItem.searchController = nil` `didPresentSearchController` calls twice and not only `UISearchController` dismissed, but whole `UIViewController` hierarchy right to `UIWindow`.  Or if i add `asyncAfter` here i get normal dismiss with expanded nav bar height, that i don't need.

**SO**

1. I think that asyncAfter in a dog-nail, how would you solve this problem?
2. How can i dismiss UISearchController correctly?

Comment: UISearchController in iOS13 unfortunately has several issues in respect to its behavior in earlier versions, another example is in the display characteristics of the SearchResultsController - it's not clear to me whether these are bugs or expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening on **iOS 13**

Add `searchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

as well as

```
`
extension SearchViewController:UISearchControllerDelegate{
    func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        if #available(iOS 13, *){
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        }
    }
    func willDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        if #available(iOS 13, *){
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the first part.

Instead of doing the async part you can use this:

```
searchController.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()        
searchController.isActive = true
```

The SearchController isn't ready at that particular moment and it needs to layout first before it can become active.

By layout-ing the searchBar we force this and it will only trigger if there's something to layout.

Comment: deejfit thanks for reply, i`ve tried to use solution with searchBar layout, but only asyncAfter works fine (